# Compiler error "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr" when using a multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have a problem with an error latex, so

I have this table, with a title, to build a title I'm using the `\multicolumn` but I have this error

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr
```

This is a minimal example

```
\documentclass[11pt]{toptesi}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
       \centering\small
           \begin{tabular}{cc}
               \toprule
                 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\large Transaction input} \\
               \midrule
               $int32\_t$ & nVersion   \\
               $uint256$ & hashPrevBlock \\
               $uint256$ & hashMerkleRoot \\
               $uint32\_t$ & nTime \\
               $uint32\_t$ & nBits \\
               $uint32\_t$ & nNonce \\
               \bottomrule
               Type & Name \\
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{Rappresentazione struttura delle transazione d’input in Bitcoin.\label{tab:inputtransaztionbitcoin}}
   \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the `&` before `\multicolumn`. But the table will not be pretty at all.

Comment: The caption text is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to the `&` in front of `\multicolumn{2}`, which is asking for a three-column row.

I see no reason to state `\small`, but if you prefer that, in no way should the table title be `\large`. Also the column headers should go on top, not at the bottom.

I added `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, which is *necessary* if you use `pdflatex` (not if you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX).

I also fixed the grammar in the caption: “transaction input” is “input di transazione”, not “transazione di input”.

The items in the first column should use either `\mathrm` (as I did here) or `\mathit`, not just math mode. An underscore seems quite unusual in math, so I changed it to mean a subscript.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{toptesi}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Transaction input} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Type} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Name} \\
\midrule
$\mathrm{int}32_t$  & nVersion   \\
$\mathrm{uint}256$  & hashPrevBlock \\
$\mathrm{uint}256$  & hashMerkleRoot \\
$\mathrm{uint}32_t$ & nTime \\
$\mathrm{uint}32_t$ & nBits \\
$\mathrm{uint}32_t$ & nNonce \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Rappresentazione della struttura degli input di transazione in 
  Bitcoin.\label{tab:inputtransaztionbitcoin}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo Do the way it's used in your field. Maybe it's `\mathrm`, maybe different.

Answer (score 2):

& is a column separator, which means that this line

```latex
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\large Transaction input} \\
```

will be interpreted as "take one column (the one before the &), then do a cell spanning two columns", essentially trying to cram three columns into the table which is defined to have only 2 columns. This throws the error your encountered.

Delete your & in that line.